# Best practice for permissions/filters in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm new in DRF and can't understand the best way to give acess only to information owned by user. I have a view:

```
class InvoiceAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = InvoiceSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Invoice.objects.filter(company__user=self.request.user)
```

Is it good enough to use filter method or maybe I should add custom permission or even go to serialization. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to limit list of objects with only those owned by current user then overriding queryset is OK.

[Permission classes](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) using to check, well, permissions based on view or object level. It would be good to use permissions if you need allow all users to see all objects, but only owner can edit specific object.